# ReactJS: Pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to setup a react project. It has lot of dependencies and while downloading one of module it is throwing this error. This is on windows.

pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

Output:
‼ unable to get local issuer certificate
 pngquant pre-build test failed
 compiling from source
 pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
 
Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed

Comment: If you have a package.json file , then try npm install , it will install all the dependencies

Comment: Got it fixed. Had version mismatch issues.

Comment: sudo apt install -y build-essential gcc make libpng-dev helped me

Comment: I fix it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308545/error-with-npm-update-pngquant-binary-does-not-seem-to-work-correctly

Answer (score 24):

You didn't installed lib-png so that error is coming.Try to install lib-png first.

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
npm install -g pngquant-bin
```

Comment: I am trying to do it on windows.

Comment: for windows try npm install --save-dev pngquant --msvs_version=2013 this one

Comment: Had to fix my versions. Node 8.11 npm 5.6 yarn 1.6

Comment: I have the same error with node 8.12 and npm 6.4.1, tried Mukesh's solution but it does not work

Answer (score 5):

To expound more on [@Mukesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279088/10907864).

I experienced this issue when building a react project that uses the `imagemin-pngquant` package.

When I run `npm install` on the server I get the below error:

```
pngquant pre-build test failed
compiling from source
pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Install libpng-dev package on your machine/server:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Add `pngquant-bin` package to your npm packages in the `package.json` file (if it doesn't yet exist):

```
"dependencies": {
  .
  .
  .
  "imagemin-pngquant": "^9.0.1",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

**OR**

Run the command to install the `pngquant-bin` package:

```
npm install imagemin-pngquant --save // to install the latest

OR

npm install imagemin-pngquant@9.0.1 --save // to install a specific version
```

**Note**: You can try `npm install imagemin-pngquant@5.0.1 --save` if you encounter issues with the latest version.

Now everything should be fine if you install the npm packages and build the project again using:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue:

Solution

Step 1

```
sudo apt-get update -y
```

Step 2

```
sudo apt-get install -y libpng-dev
```

These two steps sorted out my issue and working fine.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu you can try to fix it with `apt-get install -y libpango1.0-dev` command, worked for older node v6

Comment: This was the fix for me on an old Vagrant box. Looks like it's expecting this or another dependent library but gives the "be sure libpng-dev is installed" error as a default message.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Windows:

- Run Windows PowerShell as Admin
- `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

If you have made any previous npm installation attempt which you most likely had, clean everything and then do a fresh dependency installation:

- `rm node_modules -R`
- `rm package-lock.json`
- `npm install`

Good luck!